# Why one of two identical associations returns an error in view (association works in console though)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, local

I created an association has_many through for 2 models: professionals and cities. They're linked by connection model (and table). I tested the association in rails console and it does return proper values. The problem appears when I try to list all connections on an index page. An association city <> connection works, but professional <> connection doesn't. Below are snippets or code related and the error I'm getting.

Professional.rb:

```
has_many :feature_connections
has_many :citycodes, :through => :feature_connections
```

Citycode.rb:

```
has_many :feature_connections
has_many :professionals, :through => :feature_connections
```

FeatureConnection.rb:

```
belongs_to :citycode
belongs_to :professional
```

Schema.rb:

```
...
create_table "feature_connections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "professional_id"
    t.integer  "citycode_id"
...
create_table "professionals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "org_name"
...
create_table "citycodes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "cityname"
...
```

Index.html.haml (for listing connections):

```
      - @feature_connections.each do |c|
        %tr
          %td= c.citycode.cityname
          %td= c.professional.org_name
```

Now the error I'm getting when trying to access the index view:

```
undefined method `org_name' for nil:NilClass
```

What is even more confusing it has worked a few days ago. I pushed that to Heroku and it still works there but not locally.

I've found those settings might affect associations but changing development didn't affect anything:

development.rb:

```
config.eager_load = false
```

production.rb:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions, ideas, and edits to this issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because one of your `feature_connections` does not have associated `professional` record. Maybe it has been accidentally deleted.

You should find this `feature_connection` and delete it. Or if empty association is allowed, you shoud check it's presence in the view before trying to get it's `org_name`:

```
  # index.html.haml
  - @feature_connections.each do |c|
    %tr
      %td= c.citycode.cityname if c.citycode
      %td= c.professional.org_name if c.professional
```

or using `try` method:

```
  # index.html.haml
  - @feature_connections.each do |c|
    %tr
      %td= c.citycode.try(:cityname)
      %td= c.professional.try(:org_name)
```

If empty association is not allowed, you should avoid this problem in the future, adding some validations and constraints:

On the model level:

```
# feature_connection.rb:
validate :citycode, :professional, presence: true

## You might also want to delete join table reords when delete an object:

# professional.rb:
has_many :feature_connections, dependent: destroy

# citycode.rb:
has_many :feature_connections, dependent: destroy
```

On the DB level (add migration):

```
# add NOT NULL constraint 
change_column :feature_connections, :citycode_id, :integer, null: false
change_column :feature_connections, :professional_id, :integer, null: false
```

You might also want to add `foreign key` constraint to prevent `citycodes` and `professionals` from removing if they have associated records (unless you are using `dependent: destroy`):

```
add_foreign_key :feature_connections, :citycodes
add_foreign_key :feature_connections, :professionals
```

Comment: I cleaned up the database and followed the route of disallowing empty associations. That must have been the issue. Works perfectly now, thank you so much!